# Overriding Active Admin batch action form view with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have added a batch action into my company tab and I want to customize the form that will be used in the action.

```
batch_action :my_action, form: {} do |ids|
  # Doesn't really do anything yet
  redirect_to collection_path
end
```

Then I have a javascript that adds a custom dialog when the batch action link is clicked

```
$ ->
  if $('body.admin_companies').length
    $('a[data-action="my_action"]').click (event) ->
      $('body').append('<div id="mys_dialog"><div id="my_dialog_content"></div></div>')
      $('#my_dialog').dialog autoOpen: true, open: (event, ui) ->
        $('#my_dialog_content').load '/admin/companies/get_partial'
      return false
```

In active admin I have also the required collection_action "get_partial" that returns the view I want to use. My view has a form that submits into an other collection_action, so it doesn't really use the batch_action into anything else than just adding the link into the batch actions drop down menu.

The issue with this is that when I click the link in the drop down menu it first shows me a dialog with the empty form that is defined in the batch_action. If I cancel in that dialog then I can see my own dialog. How could I prevent the default dialog from showing up?

I tried adding `$('a[data-action="my_action"]').unbind()` into my javascript but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to catch the submit action

```
$ ->
  if $('body.admin_companies').length
    $('#collection_selection').submit (event) ->
      if $('#batch_action').val() == 'my_action'
        ...
```

With this I don't need the empty form in the batch_action at all.